# iOS Parse - Delete & Update Record

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS app with multiple procedures executing. One of the procedures is registering a user. In total this process currently requires approximately 7 requests to Parse backend to complete. I am trying to optimize the number of requests i.e. reduce them.

I have this code that basically check if array value in Parse class is empty or not. If not empty then I empty it and make another request afterwards to add the new value. How can I make this in a single request? i.e. a request to erase current value of array column in Parse class and insert two elements into this array (latitude and longitude)?

Some of the code responsible for the operation

```
/*To clear existing values in array*/
            let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")

            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
                    print("No Errors.........")
                    gameScore.removeObjectsInArray(self.tempWorkAddressValues, forKey: "workAddress")
                    print("Step 1 Completed")
                    gameScore.saveInBackground()
                    print("successfully cleared array")
                }
            }

            /*to add new elemnets to array*/
            let query2 = PFQuery(className:"_User")

            query2.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
                    print("No Errors.........")
                    gameScore.addObjectsFromArray(self.userObject.workAddress, forKey: "workAddress")
                    print("Step 2 Completed")
                    gameScore.saveInBackground()
                    print("successfully updated array")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addressWorkBackToProfileSegue", sender: sender);

                }
            }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You re aware that your two queries may run in parallel, rather than one after the other? Also why re-fetch the same object? Why save before adding the additional data? And why use an array if you only ever store a single value?

Comment: @jcaron I am not storing a single value. I am storing two items which are latitude and longitude. I could store them in a string and then part with a separator, but thought the arrays were cleaner.

Comment: @jcaron yes I realize also that they may run in parallel. I will fix that using completion once I find a better way to minimize the requests.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`PFGeoPoint`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints)?

Comment: @jcaron I already investigated that earlier but you can't have more than one  column of its type in a class. I store work and home addresses, so it will be pointless

Comment: Create a separate class for "address" with the geo point in there, and create two such instances for each user?

Comment: Or use two numeric fields, one for latitude, one for longitude (for each of the addresses)

Comment: yup that's a workaround...but to be honest I went straight to the array thinking it was logical. I am actually updating it now to use the string option better. Easier to set and update (also avoids the loops)